# mysql euro symbol returns question mark

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert euro symbol to mysql, here is the create statement,

```
CREATE TABLE `symbol` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `currency` VARCHAR(5) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO symbol (currency) VALUES ('€')
```

Mysql shows (?).

I went through a lot of examples on stack overflow changing charset to utf-8 and so on but I am not sure whats going on.
I would like to use latin1 since I want Finnish characters.

Comment: Use UTF-8, it has support for every character in the world. There's extremely little reason to use latin1 today, and this is not one of them.

Comment: To clarify, I think @Evert means to use `CHARSET=UTF-8`

Comment: @Evert I used CHARSET=UTF-8, did not work.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE `symbol` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `currency` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
```